# Unity game online beta testing platform

Tags: testing, unity-game-engine, beta, testflight

I've googled this but, nothing useful came up. It's really simple, i'm looking for a service that supports Unity games distribution and usage tracking, with crash reports and whatnot, something like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) or [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/) but for Unity games!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What platform is your Unity game for? There's a plugin for the TestFlight SDK for Unity iOS in the Asset Store, and there's an open source one too. https://github.com/darktable/TestFlightUnity

Comment: @Calvin Thanks for the info ! PC, don't mind if it asked specifically for some deploy type (standalone / flash / unity web), it would just be used for testing anw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for "analytics" in the Unity Asset Store there are some systems that support Unity PC.  These can be used to track usage, and some track errors too.  Usually analytics systems support attaching extra data to an event, and you could use this to send uncaught exceptions to the service.

[Application.RegisterLogCallback](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.RegisterLogCallback.html) can be used for this.

```
void OnEnable() {
    Application.RegisterLogCallback(ErrorReporter);
}

void OnDisable() {
    Application.RegisterLogCallback(null);
}

void ErrorReporter (string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type) {
    if (type == LogType.Assert || type == LogType.Error || type == LogType.Exception) {
        // send analytics message with logString and/or stackTrace attached.
    }
}
```